# How to get GPU usage and GPU memory info of a process by powershell7

Tags: windows-10, powershell, gpu, powershell-7.0

I have tried `Get-Process` and `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process` to get GPU usage and GPU memory, but both of them can't offer those information.

In Windows Task Manager, it can show GPU memory.

So, is there a way to get those in powershell

Comment: Have you tried anything around `Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried too.But it doesn't help

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - PowerShell 7.1 is literally the next version and is nearly a full replacement for PowerShell 5.1;  5.1 isn’t being developed and 7.1 should be used instead

Comment: @Ramhound - what you just said is what i said. [*grin*] yes it is the NEXT version ... but it aint technically an UPGRADE ... at least not yet. for windows, the ONLY version that is fully supported is ps5.1 ... ps7 is a side-grade that lacks full compatibility. **_ps7 otta be when it offers something useful that ps5.1 does not._** the web cmdlets are prime examples of why one would use ps7 instead of ps5.1 at this time

Comment: PS 7.1 is nearly a full replacement for 5.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows uses [Performance Counters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/about-performance-counters) to track this type of thing. You can get the values in powershell via `Get-Counter`. Depending on your GPU and drivers, you may have more specific counters available, but these examples should always be available:

```
# Example to get GPU usage counters for a specific process:
$p = Get-Process dwm
((Get-Counter "\GPU Process Memory(pid_$($p.id)*)\Local Usage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue | 
    foreach {Write-Output "Process $($P.Name) GPU Process Memory $([math]::Round($_/1MB,2)) MB"}
((Get-Counter "\GPU Engine(pid_$($p.id)*engtype_3D)\Utilization Percentage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue |
    foreach {Write-Output "Process $($P.Name) GPU Engine Usage $([math]::Round($_,2))%"}

# Outputs:
Process dwm GPU Process Memory 259.36 MB
Process dwm GPU Engine Usage 0.47%


# Example to get total GPU usage counters:
$GpuMemTotal = (((Get-Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Local Usage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue | measure -sum).sum
    Write-Output "Total GPU Process Memory Local Usage: $([math]::Round($GpuMemTotal/1MB,2)) MB"
$GpuUseTotal = (((Get-Counter "\GPU Engine(*engtype_3D)\Utilization Percentage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue | measure -sum).sum
    Write-Output "Total GPU Engine Usage: $([math]::Round($GpuUseTotal,2))%"

# Outputs:
Total GPU Process Memory Local Usage: 511.36 MB
Total GPU Engine Usage: 0.77%
```

I found these counter names by running `Get-Counter -ListSet 'GPU*'`, and taking the `Counter` values from there. It looks like GPU engine usage is broken down into 4 types:

```
engtype_3D
engtype_VideoDecode
engtype_Copy
engtype_VideoProcessing
```

I'm just summing `engtype_3D` in the example, since it is the only one with usage on my system. These values all match up with what displays in windows Task Manager, so it should be accurate enough.

Comment: Thanks!! I do can get GPU memory usage from `Get-Counter`. Although `Get-Counter` run few second.